# Using Matter.js, how to position SVG paths in a compound body?

Tags: matter.js

I'm trying to create a capital letter "A" as an SVG shape for use with [Matter.js](https://brm.io/matter-js/docs/) but the letter shape displays incorrectly.

[CodePen here](https://codepen.io/ChrisBup/pen/ZErNLpg) and duplicated here:

```js
function percentX(percent) {
  return Math.round((percent / 100) * window.innerWidth);
}
function percentY(percent) {
  return Math.round((percent / 100) * window.innerHeight);
}

const Engine = Matter.Engine,
      Bodies = Matter.Bodies,
      Body = Matter.Body,
      Svg = Matter.Svg,
      Vertices = Matter.Vertices,
      Composite = Matter.Composite,
      Render = Matter.Render,
      Runner = Matter.Runner;

// create an engine
const engine = Engine.create(),
      world = engine.world;

// create a renderer
const render = Render.create({
  element: document.body,
  engine: engine,
  options: {
    wireframes: false,
    showInternalEdges: false,
    width: percentX(100),
    height: percentY(100),
    background: "transparent"
  }
});

let bodies = [],
    bgColor = "#0A0618";

// SVGs

let vertexSets = [],
    svgLetter,
    svgLetterLegOne,
    svgLetterLegTwo,
    svgLetterCounter;

let letterX = percentX(60);
let letterY = percentY(20);

let letterXLegOne = percentX(60) - 40;
let letterYLegOne = percentY(20) + 40;

let letterXLegTwo = percentX(60) + 40;
let letterYLegTwo = percentY(20) + 40;

let letterSize = (window.innerWidth / 1000);

// A

// silhouette test (incorrectly displaying Batman ears)

$('#svg-test').find('path').each(function(i, path) {

  svgTest = Bodies.fromVertices(
    percentX(30),
    letterY,
    Vertices.scale(Svg.pathToVertices(path, 10), 
    letterSize,
    letterSize), {
      render: {
        fillStyle: "white",
        strokeStyle: "white",
        lineWidth: 2
      }
    }, true);

  vertexSets.push(svgTest);

});

// letter base shape

$('#svg-3').find('path').each(function(i, path) {

  svgLetter = Bodies.fromVertices(
    letterX,
    letterY,
    Vertices.scale(Svg.pathToVertices(path, 10), 
    letterSize,
    letterSize), {
      render: {
        fillStyle: "yellow",
        strokeStyle: "yellow",
        lineWidth: 2
      }
    }, true);

  vertexSets.push(svgLetter);

});

// left leg

$('#svg-3-leg-1').find('path').each(function(i, path) {

  svgLetterLegOne = Bodies.fromVertices(
    letterXLegOne,
    letterYLegOne,
    Vertices.scale(Svg.pathToVertices(path, 10), 
    letterSize,
    letterSize), {
      render: {
        fillStyle: "green",
        strokeStyle: "green",
        lineWidth: 2,
        isStatic: true
      }
    }, true);

  vertexSets.push(svgLetterLegOne);

});

// right leg

$('#svg-3-leg-2').find('path').each(function(i, path) {
  
  svgLetterLegTwo = Bodies.fromVertices(
    letterXLegTwo,
    letterYLegTwo,
    Vertices.scale(Svg.pathToVertices(path, 10), 
    letterSize,
    letterSize), {
      render: {
        fillStyle: "blue",
        strokeStyle: "blue",
        lineWidth: 2,
        isStatic: true
      }
    }, true);

  vertexSets.push(svgLetterLegTwo);

});

// counter (hole in the center), no need for offset repositioning

$('#svg-3-counter').find('path').each(function(i, path) {

  svgLetterCounter = Bodies.fromVertices(
    letterX,
    letterY,
    Vertices.scale(Svg.pathToVertices(path, 10), 
    letterSize,
    letterSize), {
      render: {
        fillStyle: bgColor,
        strokeStyle: bgColor,
        lineWidth: 2
      }
    }, true);

  vertexSets.push(svgLetterCounter);

});

// create compound body for letter "A"
var compoundBodyA = Body.create({
  parts: [svgLetter, svgLetterLegOne, svgLetterLegTwo, svgLetterCounter]
});

// add A and O compound bodies to the world
Composite.add(world, [
  compoundBodyA
]);

// add all SVGs to the world
Composite.add(world, vertexSets);

// run the renderer
Render.run(render);

// create runner
const runner = Runner.create();

// run the engine
Runner.run(runner, engine);

// hold in place for testing
world.gravity.y = 0;
world.gravity.x = 0;
```

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*, *::before, *::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
*:focus, *::before:focus, *::after:focus {
  outline: none;
}

* {
  font-family: monaco, courier;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #0A0618;
}

svg {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pathseg@1.2.1/pathseg.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/poly-decomp@0.3.0/build/decomp.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/matter-js/0.18.0/matter.min.js"></script>

<svg class="svg-letter" id="svg-test">
  <path class="st0" d="M59.3,0h46.4l59,141h-50.8l-7.4-18.8h-49L50.3,141h-50L59.3,0z"/>
</svg>

<svg class="svg-letter" id="svg-3">
  <path d="M57.2,122.2H7.9L59,0h46.4l51.1,122.2h-50.3H57.2z"/>
</svg>

<svg class="svg-letter" id="svg-3-leg-1">
  <path d="M0,141l7.9-18.8h49.3L50,141H0z"/>
</svg>

<svg class="svg-letter" id="svg-3-leg-2">
  <path d="M106.2,122.2h50.3l7.9,18.8h-50.8L106.2,122.2z"/>
</svg>

<svg class="svg-letter" id="svg-3-counter">
  <path d="M94.6,89L81.8,55L69,89H94.6z"/>
</svg>
```

I know Matter.js can't always handle SVGs with compound paths (an internal path creating a knockout) so my plan was to have two separate paths, the silhouette of the shape and the knockout, and group them as a compound body. Only the silhouette isn't even displaying correctly (the white version on the left). For some reason, the shape always has those Batman ears which I can't get rid of.

[image]

So my new plan is to break the silhouette shape into three parts, the main body (in yellow) and two legs (green and blue). That allows all three parts to have only four sides which seems to prevent the bug.

My problem is positioning those two legs so that they are always precisely butting up against the main body shape. I can adjust the position offset to accomplish this but since I've set the width and height of the render object to be proportional to the width and height of the browser, the letter breaks apart if the page is loaded in any other sized window.

Using variables (lines 45–54), I've tried setting the width and height of the legs to reference the main body shape with offsets:

```
svgThree.position.x - 40,
svgThree.position.y + 40,
```

And I've tried keeping all units and offsets proportional:

```
percentX(60) - percentX(2),
percentY(20) + percentX(2),
```

But nothing works. Without setting the letter to exact pixel dimensions, is there any way to keep these three paths touching and in precise relation to each other across different browser sizes?

Alternatively, if there's any way to build that SVG shape to avoid that bug, I'd greatly appreciate such a solution.

(Using Chrome Version 102.0.5005.115)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a perfect solution but the one I eventually went with was this:

Setting the letter size to a static number (0.8), instead of a derivation of the window width, allowed me to set the width and height of the two legs of the letter to a static offset distance from the main body shape, so the change in the original CodePen above would be to lines 48–54:

```
let letterXLegOne = letterX - 43;
let letterYLegOne = letterY + 49;

let letterXLegTwo = letterX + 43;
let letterYLegTwo = letterY + 49;

let letterSize = 0.8;
```

The fix is incorporated into [this CodePen](https://codepen.io/ChrisBup/pen/eYVaQbp) as a final product.